# Syntax like Superagent, how can I do it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, superagent

A few day ago I was looking at [Superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) module and I was wondering how a code should be  made to support a syntax like `request('url', callback);` and like `request.get('url').end(callback);` at the same time.

I tried to look at the source, but I didn't understand how it's made.

Can anyone tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to define a module with a similar API...

`Function`s in JavaScript are a type of `Object`, so references to them can be passed around and they can be given properties, including other `function`s as methods.

In this case, [`request` is just a `function`](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/0.17.0/lib/client.js#L866-L893) with [`get` assigned as one of its properties](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/0.17.0/lib/client.js#L895-L911):

```
function request(method, url) {
  // ...

  return new Request(method, url);
}

request.get = function(url, data, fn){
  var req = request('GET', url);

  // ...

  return req;
};
```

With either, the value `return`ed is a [`Request` instance](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/0.17.0/lib/client.js#L436-L457), which has [an `end` method](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/0.17.0/lib/client.js#L783-L858) that continues to `return` the instance.

```
Request.prototype.end = function(fn) {
  // ...

  return this;
};
```

This allows for a [fluent API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) with [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining):

```
request
  .get('...', function () {})
  .end(function () {});
  .end(function () {});
```

```
// that does the same as...
var req = request.get('...', function () {});
req.end(function () {});
req.end(function () {});
```

Comment: You might also mention returning `this`... I think he's asking about chaining.